# Architecture vue application

Tags: javascript, vue.js, architecture

The application has various tools (Pages) with its structure. For example, the hotel search tool (in the left pane of the list, on the right map), or the report tool (full width page), and there are many such tools.

I found an interesting component for working with panels on [github](https://github.com/antoniandre/splitpanes). And he began to do something like this:

```
//MyPanes.vue
<splitpanes class="default-theme" horizontal>
        <span>
            <div class="left-panel"><slot name="left"></slot></div> 
        </span>
        <span splitpanes-min="20" splitpanes-max="50" :splitpanes-default="horizontal_splitter[1]">
            <div class="right-panel"><slot name="right"></slot></div>
        </span>
</splitpanes>

//HotelTool.vue      
<MyPanes>
      <template slot="left">
        <v-btn @click.native="add">Add counter</v-btn>
      </template>
      <template slot="right">
        <div>{{ counter }}</div>
        <v-map />
      </template>
</MyPanes>

..
data: {
   counter: 0
},
methods: {
   add() { this.counter++; }
}
..
```

The counter is made for the test. But it does not work. Probably because the contents of the slot does not know about the data of the parent.

Thus the question arises. How to implement this behavior? Need to abandon slots?

Of course, you can do it via event bus or store, but I have a lot of tools, and it’s not very convenient to transfer data in this way. I would like to create the instrument in one file, write logic in it for the left and right parts so that they know about each other. And so do all the tools.

Could you share your thoughts? How to change data between slots in the context of a single parent? And are there any other solutions?

[Example tool](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5xzWK.jpg)
[Example tool](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NhP0C.jpg)
On the left and right side there may be different components.

Full code:

```
<template>
    <MyPanes>
        <template v-slot:left>
            <h1>Мониторинг</h1>
            <v-btn @click.native="add">{{ counter }}</v-btn>
        </template>
        <template v-slot:right>
            {{counter}}
        </template>
    </MyPanes>
</template>

<script>
    export default {
        data() {
            return {
                counter: 0,
            }
        },
        methods: {
            add: function () {
                this.counter++;
            }
        }
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Scenario solution

There shouldn't be an issue here with data scope because the reference to the data is all done inside the 'HotelTool' instance.

Don't forget that 'data' is a function that returns an object in Vue:

```
data() {
   return {
       counter: 0
   }
},
methods: {
   add() { this.counter++; }
}
```

Please also update your @click event to fire passively by replacing the **.native** with **.passive**:

```
<v-btn @click.passive="add">Add counter</v-btn>
```

### Splitpanes Reactivity

Splitpanes documentation claims to disable or block reactivity by default on [their website](https://antoniandre.github.io/splitpanes/). You can add the **watch-slots** element to restore reactivity.

```
<splitpanes watch-slots class="default-theme" horizontal>
....
```

---

## General answer: Passing data between Vue instances

As a more general answer for future readers asking the same question, sharing data between instances in Vue can be achieved by:

Passing to props and emitting with events (recommended):
[VueJS.org Props](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-props.html) and,
[VueJS.org Custom Events](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-custom-events.html)

A global data 'store':
[Vuex Guide](https://vuex.vuejs.org/guide/)

I would recommend getting used to the first option, as this is recommended in the Vue documentation and adequate for most scenarios. The Vuex approach starts to become useful for larger applications.

Tip: Vue's console errors are pretty useful and often the first place to look for errors involving scope. They also offer a Chrome extension to help give visibility of your applications state in real time.

Comment: I inserted a detailed example of my code into the header. This is for some reason not working. The counter increases, but in slots it is equal to 0.

Comment: Try to change the click event from native to passive. I believe the button's native event is stopping your click event from firing the add function.

@click.passive="add()" in lieu of @click.native="add"

Comment: console.log (this.counter) - works, but the DOM is not updated

Comment: hrm... try replacing the v-slot:left / v-slot:right with slot="left" / slot="right". I have managed to get a working version of it here using standard DIV tags instead of the 'splitpanes' element. I'll try do a CodePen for you

Comment: it would be convenient if all parts of the tool were in the same file (left, right), and they would have common methods and variables. Without the need to create a store, event bus, etc.

Comment: Hi, the splitpanes elements are blocking reactivity for 'perofmance' reasons (detailed on their website). You can add the 'watch-slots' attribute to the splitpanes elements to restore reactivity. Note: on ordinary elements, if you were to replace each 'splitpanes' element with divs for example, this property reactivity works as expected.

Comment: Wow, it works! Thanks you. I wonder how much this affects performance ..

Comment: You're welcome. I can't say I've worked with the splitpanes part much but im not convinced it provides much you couldn't do yourself with some pretty basic HTML & CSS. I am most of the way through a huge API driven Vue project myself and found huge value in having a page-wide store, especially when managing 60+ custom elements on SPA.

Comment: Ps. Hopefully we've managed to answer your question? I have updated the answer. Please mark accordingly if so :)